# Get value from DropDownList, use it in ActionLink (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink, html-select

I have this in my View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropBox", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectedListItems)
```

I would like to get the selected value from the dropBox and post it back to the controller using like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add","AddAction", "AddController", new {@accessID = *here*})
```

*here* is where I'd just like to add "dropBox".SelectedValue, but how do I do this?

How else could I post back the SelectedValue of the dropBox?

Comment: Can you use Ajax post?

Comment: Probably, my front end knowledge isn't the best. I've heard about Ajax several times, I've just never used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the actionlink  helper is rendered at the server, the value of the dropdown is selected by the user at the client side

so what you can do is something like this:

```
        <a id='badd'>add</a>
        <script>
         $('#badd').click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             window.location.replace = 
    '<%=Url.Action("Add","AddAction", "AddController")%>' + '?accessID='+ $('#dropBox').val();
             });
        </script>
```

Comment: Much appriciated! :) Thanks.